# Thumbnails with Zurb Foundation and RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation, frontend

So I recently started using Zurb Foundation, and following [this documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/thumbnails.html).

I have the following code which are links to all the designs in the database.

```
<div>
  <div class="small-4 small-offset-4 rows"><h2>Most Downloaded</h2></div>
  <% @designs.each do |design| %>
    <div><%= link_to design.title, design_path(design) %></div>  
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I wanted help on creating thumbnails for each link. Just to get the gist of it, I wanted to use the same picture for all thumbnails. I used a.th class to wrap the image but I wanted to learn how to display more than one (typically 3) thumbnails on each row.

So lets say there are 9 designs in total, I wanted 3 rows of 3 thumbnails each. I wasn't able to find many tutorials/explanations for this so any tips would be helpful to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Foundation's block grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html.

I think it does just what you're after. To get a 3 by 3 thumbnail grid would look something like:

```
    <div>
      <div class="small-4 small-offset-4 rows"><h2>Most Downloaded</h2></div>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
            <% @designs.each do |design| %>
              <li><%= link_to design.title, design_path(design), class: "th" %></li>  
            <% end %>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```